# Is it possible to run Junit tests automatically when saving a file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit

We have a java project in Eclipse with classes and their associated JUnit test classes.  We can run these tests using Junit and Maven manually inside Eclipse, but would like them to be run automatically whenever a Java file in the project is saved.

Is there anyway of doing this?  I've been searching for awhile and might have missed it or not understood but whatever I've tried it doesn't seem to be calling Maven when we save a file despite having the MavenBuilder selected.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Z

Comment: BTW I know that there are plugins like Infinitest that check all projects and run any tests they find, but I thought this should be possible using Maven (or maybe even Ant) instead.

Comment: Maybe infinitest is the tool that you are looking for? -> http://infinitest.github.io/